# Facebook API: how to get event details

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Trying to get the details of all events me/my friends are attending/maybe attending in the coming month (date manipulations in the FQL).

I am also in need of getting those events' feeds for further analysis in my program.

So far I found Facebook API's documentation hardly any helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the event and event_member tables in conjunction with the friend table to get this data.
Eg: 
`SELECT eid, name, location, start_time FROM event WHERE eid in ( select eid from event_member where rsvp_status != 'declined' and uid = me() or uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me()) ) AND start_time >= '2012-08-01' and start_time <= '2012-08-31'`

Comment: Great answer, thank you! I actualy got this by now though :-)